# Android - Unnable to connect to node.js server with HttpURLConnection (Connection closed by peer)

Tags: android, json, node.js, api, server

I have a simple **node.js** server running at localhost:8080 which serves a simple api (json). Everything works fine on the browser. I've also made an **android** app that should connect and get json file from localhost:8080 , but simply refuses with error when connection `javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Connection closed by peer`. It is working with other websites, but not my own node.js server.

I am using AsyncTask to retrive request in the background which looks like this:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    String result = "";

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    int statusCode = 0;

    try {
        URL url = new URL(params[0]);

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

        statusCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("Async call code: " + connection.getResponseCode());

        if (statusCode ==  200) {
            System.out.println("Server responded with code: " + statusCode);

            InputStream inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

            String line = "";
            String res = "";

            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                res += line;
            }

            /* Close Stream */
            if(null!=inputStream){
                inputStream.close();
            }

            parseResult(res);

        }
        else{
            System.out.println("error");
        }

    } catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    finally {
        connection.disconnect();
        System.out.println("disconnected");
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: What's `params[0]`? I note that the exception you're getting suggests your code is trying to make an HTTPS connection, so is `localhost:8080` HTTPS or HTTP? The port number strongly suggests it's HTTP, but if it is HTTPS (in which case I'd move it to 8443 just to make it clear it's HTTPS), does it have a valid cert? If not, have you arranged for your code to accept self-signed certs?

Comment: Hello thanks for trying to help, you fixed my help. param[0] was https://localhost:8443 which is wrong, it should have been http://localhost:8443. Thanks it works now!

Comment: Sorry but i do not believe that your android app can use localhost as host name to connect to a server on your pc. Impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by changing url from https://localhost:8443 to http://localhost:8443. This url is passed as param[0] to the code above. Now everythig works fine!

Comment: Presumably you mean from `:8443` to `:8080`? And glad you got it working.

Comment: Works with both 8080 and 8443